# How to return when looped variable amount of times

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just going through some practice exercises, this one asks to create a dice roller that will generate a random number. The arguments of the function are supposed to be (number of sides on dice, Number of Rolls)

If I just use return it will stop the loop. I know a way around this is to combine the answers and print that but what if the amount of answers (or rolls in this case) is a variable?

Here is my code:

```
#roll_dice
import random

def rolldice(sides, rolls):
  start = 1
  while start <= rolls:
    number = random.randint(1, sides)
    start += 1
  return number

print rolldice(6, 3)
```

How can I get this to print this:

```
3
5
2
```

Comment: Give your variables names, not b and x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `yield`

```
import random

def rolldice(sides, rolls):
  for i in xrange(0, rolls):
    yield random.randint(1, sides)

for item in rolldice(6,3):
  print item
```

Comment: `lst` is a bit misleading since it's an iterator.  Simpler to do `for item in rolldice(6, 3): ...`.  Also use `xrange()` instead of manually incrementing a counter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension like following, which will makes your function returns a list of random numbers:

```
>>> import random
>>> def rolldice(sides, rolls):
...     return [random.randint(1, sides) for _ in xrange(rolls)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> rolldice(6, 3)
[1, 2, 3]
>>> rolldice(6, 3)
[2, 6, 4]
```

Comment: This doesn't print exactly how I wanted it but it is very concise and gets the job done.  Thanks!

Comment: You can get it to print exactly how you wanted by calling it like this `print("\n".join([str(x) for x in rolldice(6,3)]))` each item will go on a newline because you use `"\n".join()`

Answer (score 1):

You want to return a list to the user, and then print out the list in your specified form:

```
#roll_dice
import random

def rolldice(sides, rolls):
  numbers = []
  index = 0
  while index < rolls:
    number = random.randint(1, sides)
    numbers.append(number)
    index += 1
  return numbers

print '\n'.join(rolldice(6, 3))
```

Comment: This is throwing me an error:    "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nhud...........", line 55, in <module>
    print '\n'.join(rolldice2(6, 3))
  File "/Users/nhud...........", line 51, in rolldice2
    numbers[index] = number
IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @SenorPenguin My apologies, that should be fixed now!